# How to override app settings in azure app service?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-appservice

net core application. I have created arm template for resource creation. In template I have passed variables like below.

```
"siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                      {
                        "name": "AzureAd:Authority",
                        "value": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "AzureAd:TenantId",
                        "value": "[parameters('azureAdTenantId')]"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "AzureAd:ClientId",
                        "value": "[parameters('azureAdAppId')]"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "Logging:LogLevel:Default",
                        "value": "Warning"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "EnableSwagger",
                        "value": "true"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "AllowedHosts",
                        "value": "*"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "AzureSQLConnectionString",
                        "value": "server=myconnstring"
                      }
                    ],
                    "alwaysOn": true
                  
            }
```

Below are parameters

```
"azureAdTenantId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "myid",
            "metadata": {
              "description": "desc"
            }
          },
          "azureAdAppId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "myid",
            "metadata": {
              "description": "desc"
            }
          }
```

Then I have below configurations in my appsettings.json file

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "mytenantid",
    "ClientId": "myclientid"
  }
}
```

Then I created release pipeline in azure devops to deploy my webapi app. It throws me below error

```
2020-07-17T13:17:58.4644065Z ##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'WebApi' application settings. Error: BadRequest - AppSetting with name 'AzureAd:Authority' is not allowed. (CODE: 400)
```

When doing deployment Do I should not pass values in appsettings because my arm template runs and it already created appsettings and put values. I am not really finding what I am missing here? Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: does it has any space characters?

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan "Authority": after this there is space

Comment: check if this helps https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7799

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan Thanks for the link but dint work for me

Comment: can you post your arm tempalte and values

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan I have added

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan. One thing i observed, application will always takes value from app service app settings configurations. So do we really need to pass the values in appsetting.json also?

Comment: I found one thing. After changing appsetting in app service plan to AzureAd__Authority error went of and succesfully deployed but problem is application is not working and seems app is unable to read config after changing to AzureAd__Authority

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218046/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-niranjan-godbole).